# Efficent collection to associate a key with multiple value Objects

Tags: java

This there any efficient collection to associate a key with multiple values, something like

```
new HashMap<K,V,V>();
```

example:

```
 new HashMap<Long, List<CustomerVO>, List<FacilityInfo>>();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Commons Multimap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) - it seems to be what you're after:

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

Alternatively, you can just stick a collection of any kind into a regular map, e.g:

```
Map<Key, Set<Value>> myMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about Plain Old Java Object approach -

```
public class CutomerFacilityDetail{
   List<CustomerVO> customvoList;
   List<FacilityInfo> facilityInfoList;
   ...<getter & setter method>
}
```

Now create map -`Map<Long,List<CutomerFacilityDetail>>`