# what type of Data Structure to be used to store this type of data?

Tags: java

I am retrieving the data from Database in this format which will be in  key , value pair .

```
| Soft Drinks        | Bottled,Lemon(19)                           
| Soft Drinks        | Bottled,Clear(20)                           
| Ice creams        | Cone,KoolCool(21)                           
| Ice creams        | Stick,KoolCool,Sai,BabaSai(27)
```

Please suggest ,Is there any data structure to store this type of data ??

The key is duplicated so i cant use Map .

Comment: Class is also a data type :-) why not use it?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24954674/717214) to another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Multimap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) it stores a Collection of entries for each key.

Comment: Could you please let me know , In what jar file , will i find this class ??

Comment: I think Apache Commons

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) that supports key duplicates